# Error in SQL Stored Procedure Logic for a Report Using a Staff Name DropDown Filter

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a report that shows the initial and most recent progress scores for a customer. One of the dropdown filters used is the 'Staff' filter that allows the user to select 'All' staff members or select a specific staff member to filter the report by.
The issue I'm encountering is that the initial and most recent scores are showing correctly when the 'Staff' dropdown filter is set to 'All', but it does not show correctly (the initial and most recent scores are the same for all clients) when the filter is set to a specific staff member's name. 
As I'm not receiving an error, I assume the syntax is correct and the issue must be with the logic. I've included a snippet of the stored procedure below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
JOIN person familymember on familymember.idfamily = family.id 
LEFT JOIN capCase cc on cc.idFamilymember = familymember.id
LEFT JOIN #applicantFamily on #applicantFamily.idfamily = Family.id --and isnumeric(@classroom) = 1
WHERE main.idSSMatrix = @idSSMatrix 
  AND main1.StartDate between @dateFrom AND @dateTo 
  AND   ( cast ( main.IdProgram as varchar ) = @idProgram OR isnumeric(@idProgram) <> 1 )
  AND   ( cast ( cc.idType as varchar ) = @idProgramCapCase OR isnumeric(@idProgramCapCase) <> 1 )
  AND   (cast( main.idstaff as varchar) = @staff OR isnumeric( @staff) <> 1)
  AND  (isnumeric(#applicantFamily.idfamily ) = 1 or (isnumeric(@classroom) <> 1 ))
  AND main1.id is not null
```

Comment: What is this for, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: What if you paste the full SELECT into Query Designer in SQL Server Visual Studio?  Does the query work from there?

Comment: Off-topic - asking for debugging help without a complete MVCE. Spamming of tags is not helping either. Erland discusses (dynamic search conditions)[http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) in great detail; you should review that and start over. And think long and hard about casting a (presumably) numeric value to "varchar" - what length string to you expect and why do you think this is needed?

Comment: This is for SQL Server, I used the MySQL tag as they basically follow the same standard .